# How to set transitions in tikz mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I have a problem with changing color of connection, why the transition is not smooth? Where circles are red I want the connection to be also red.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \path[mindmap,
  text=black,
  grow cyclic
  level 1/.append style={level distance=5cm,sibling angle=60},
  level 3/.append style={sibling angle=40},
  every node/.style = {concept},
  concept color=orange!60
]
    node[concept color=yellow!85] {Parametry}
    child[concept color=yellow!85, grow=240] {
      node[concept color=yellow ] {Wejściowe}
      [clockwise from=-60]
      child { node[concept color=yellow!85] {Strumień masowy\\ $\dot{m}_{w}$   } }
      child { node[concept color=yellow!85,text width=4.6em] {Temperatura\\ $\dot{T}_{w}$  } }
      child { node[concept color=yellow!85] {Ciśnienie\\ $\dot{P}_{w}$  } }
    }
    %child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {technical} }
    child[concept grow=300] {
    node[concept color=yellow] {Wyjściowe}
    [clockwise from=-10]
    child { 
      node[concept color=red!70] {Ciepły koniec}
      [clockwise from=50]
      child { node[concept color=red!70] {Strumień masowy\\ $\dot{m}_{c}$} }
      child { node[concept color=red!70,text width=3.6em] {Temperatura\\\\$T_{c}$} }
      child { node[concept color=red!70] {Ciśnienie\\ $\dot{P}_{c}$} }
    }
    child { 
      node[concept color=blue!60 ] {Zimny Koniec}
      child { node[concept color=blue!60,text width=3.6em,grow=0] {Temperatura\\\\$T_{z}$} } %,text width=4em,grow=315
      child { node[concept color=blue!60, grow=25] {Strumień masowy\\ $\dot{m}_{z}$} }  %scale=1.2,grow=215
      child { node[concept color=blue!60,grow=0] {Ciśnienie\\ $\dot{P}_{z}$} }  %,minimum size=1cm,grow=115
    }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. There is an out-of-place `}`, and also a missing `,`. What colour should the connections for the blue circles be?

Answer (score 1):

Some typing errors were in the MWE.

Without them, this produces:

[image: Paramtery]

MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \path[mindmap,
  text=black,
  grow cyclic
  level 1/.append style={level distance=5cm,sibling angle=60},
  level 3/.append style={sibling angle=40},
  every node/.style = {concept},
  concept color=orange!60
]
    node[concept color=yellow!85] {Parametry}
    child[concept color=yellow!85, grow=240] {
      node[concept color=yellow ] {Wejściowe}
      [clockwise from=-60]
      child { node[concept color=yellow!85] {Strumień masowy\\ $\dot{m}_{w}$   } }
%      }
      child { node[concept color=yellow!85,text width=4.6em] {Temperatura\\ $\dot{T}_{w}$  } }
%      }
      child { node[concept color=yellow!85] {Ciśnienie\\ $\dot{P}_{w}$  } }
    }
    child[concept color=red, grow=300] {
    node[concept color=yellow] {Wyjściowe}
    [clockwise from=-10]
    child { 
      node[concept color=red!70] {Ciepły koniec}
      [clockwise from=50]
      child { node[concept color=red!70] {Strumień masowy\\ $\dot{m}_{c}$}} 
      child { node[concept color=red!70,text width=3.6em] {Temperatura\\$T_{c}$} }
      child { node[concept color=red!70] {Ciśnienie\\ $\dot{P}_{c}$} }
      }
    child { 
      node[concept color=blue!60 ] {Zimny Koniec}
      child { node[concept color=blue!60,text width=3.6em,grow=0] {Temperatura\\\ \\$T_{z}$} } %,text width=4em,grow=315
      child { node[concept color=blue!60, grow=25] {Strumień masowy\\ $\dot{m}_{z}$} }  
      child { node[concept color=blue!60,grow=0] {Ciśnienie\\ $\dot{P}_{z}$} }  
      }}
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```